# Globalization errors when running Entity Framework migrations on Linux

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, docker, ubuntu

I use Zorin OS Core 16 and I'm working on a faculty project in ASP.NET.
I'm running dotnet version 6.0.201, using Intellij Rider as IDE. Since the project is microservice oriented it would be way too large to post the entire code (and I cannot post relevant parts as I'm not sure what's relevant and what isn't) so feel free to look at the [repository](https://github.com/VladimirV99/Projektor/tree/feature/movies-seed) (I've linked the branch), focusing on the *Services/Movies/Movies.API*

I've ran the docker container using:

```
docker run --name mssql -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=MatfRs2_Movies" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

And now I'm trying to run the database migration using

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Depending on the exact way in which I run the command I get somewhat different errors. If I run it just like this I get:

```
Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode()
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.CreateCultureWithInvariantData()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_Invariant()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_CachedCulturesByName()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(System.String)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetNeutralResourcesLanguage(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Resources.UltimateResourceFallbackLocation ByRef)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.CommonAssemblyInit()
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager..ctor(System.String, System.Reflection.Assembly)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Properties.Resources..cctor()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Properties.Resources.GetString(System.String, System.String[])
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Properties.Resources.get_DotnetEfFullName()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Configure(Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Naturally I've googled this problem intensively, and most answers say that setting the environment variable `DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT` to `0` solves the problem. So I've tried with `DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=0 dotnet ef database update` but that yields the same error.

Then (because why not) I tried with the value 1 which yields this error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Exe.Run(String executable, IReadOnlyList`1 args, String workingDirectory, Boolean interceptOutput)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Project.FromFile(String file, String buildExtensionsDir, String framework, String configuration, String runtime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute(String[] _)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Other things I've tried:

- Running all the variations of the command from the project root directory and from Movies.API directory
- Placing the environment variable directly into docker run command (with -e flag)
- Reinstalling dotnet sdk and runtime, both using snap and apt
- Restarting the computer

Nothing worked.
What's even more interesting is that my friend tried it on his Linux PC running Fedora 35 (though using podman instead of docker), and everything worked fine (even without setting the env variable to zero). And to make it even more confusing, by setting the env variable to 1 he managed to reproduce my **first** error (which is the one where I use 0), and that appears to be the expected behaviour for all other people who have asked about this problem online -- 0 good, 1 bad.

I hope someone has some ideas because I would really like to avoid reinstalling my system/installing Windows and such drastic solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

first install **icu** package in your linux distro.
like `pacman -S icu` in archLinux.

then add this line in .bashrc `export CLR_ICU_VERSION_OVERRIDE="50.2"`. **50.2** is installed version of icu and done.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60439#issuecomment-1100867919